# Find last updated date from a table in SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to find last time updated date from a table without using **sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats**?? I have been searching for this for an hour now but all answers I found were using this property which seems to be reset on SQL database restart.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you actually trying to find? The last time the table was updated, the last time an index was updated, the last time a row int he table was updated?

Comment: Why can't  you use `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`?

Comment: @SeanLange I am trying to find the last time a row inserted? The reason why I am trying find the last update time is to find all unused tables in the database. There are many tables and some of the tables do not have timestamp in it. And the database was restarted few days ago, so sys.dm_db_index_stats cannot be used.

Comment: @Jaberwocky Comment above. The database was restarted few days ago.

Comment: Can you just wait a few hours/days and then assert that anything not in index_usage_stats by that point is unused? Otherwise, for those table without a datestamp, I think you're probably out of luck.

Comment: @Xedni I dont think that will work for me because most of those tables were created few years back by many others. T.,T

Comment: Not sure what the creation date has to do with it. dm_db_index_usage_stats should start collecting data as soon as the server starts up. Even if they're 10 years old, an insert today will be registered there.

Comment: @Xedni Those unused tables do not have any interactions at all. So I do not think dm_"db_index_usage_stats" will help me to find those tables.

Comment: I would recommend you not relying on that view to determine tables that are not used. It is just too risky. Many systems have processes that are used very rarely (like once a year) but are very important to those processes. Just be careful. If anything, just rename the tables to add a _delete extension or something so that if one of those forgotten processed crashes you can fix it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property (**which is greatly advised**).
Or you can code your own `ON UPDATE TRIGGER` that will populate this table
(or another homemade) on its own.

Also if you just wish to collect some data about current usage,
you can setup a SQL Profiler that will do the job
(then parse the results somehow, Excel or whatever)

Last option, restore successively the backups you have taken (on a copy).
Hoping you have enough backup retention to find the data you're searching for.